# Get data from angular service and console log it

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to console.log data in my app.component file coming my service file. I am getting undefined.

Here is my code

**service.ts**

```
getBillingCycles() {
    return this.http.get('../../assets/download_1.json');
};
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    title = 'ngMTN';
    billing: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private BillingCyclesService: BillingCyclesServiceService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getBillingCycles();
    }

    getBillingCycles() {
        this.BillingCyclesService.getBillingCycles()
        .subscribe(data => this.billing = data);
        console.log(this.billing);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to place the console log within the subscribe,

```
this.BillingCyclesService.getBillingCycles()
        .subscribe((data) => {
         this.billing = data;
         console.log(this.billing);
});
```

Comment: Agree, that's one of the problem on Typescript. That sometimes the code is not been executed secuently and you need to `force` or `wait` using methods like `subscribe`